# Carregar arquivo Json com Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Como fazer para carregar um arquivo Json no meu html. O console não demonstra nenhum erro, porém não é preenchido nenhum campo com os dados do arquivo Json.

```
<h3 class="center">Tela de alunos</h3>

<div class="container">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 offset-s1">
                <input placeholder="Nome do aluno" id="aluno" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="aluno"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input placeholder="Série" id=serie type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="serie"></label>
            </div>  
            <div class="input-field col s1">
                <input placeholder="Classe" id=classe type="text" class="center validate">
                <label for="classe"></label>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col s12 l6">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn left" onclick="loadDoc()">Carregar</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn right">Editar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Segue o Javascript

```
    function loadDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var students = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var degrees = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                var classes = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("aluno").value = students[0].name;
                    document.getElementById("serie").value = degrees[0].degreeId;
                    document.getElementById("classe").value = classes[0].classId;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "students.json", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Onde está o JSON? é um ficheiro ou vais buscar na internet? Podes colocar o código que já tens?

Comment: @Sergio Em um arquivo no mesmo diretório do html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque os IDs com aspas e em tag input você deve colocar `.value` e não `.innerHTML`

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s5 offset-s1">
                <input placeholder="Nome do aluno" id="aluno" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="aluno"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s3">
                <input placeholder="Série" id="serie" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="serie"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s1">
                <input placeholder="Classe" id="classe" type="text" class="center validate">
                <label for="classe"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col s12 l6">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn left" onclick="loadDoc()">Carregar</a>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn right">Editar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function loadDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                document.getElementById("aluno").value = json[0].name;
                document.getElementById("serie").value = json[0].degreeId;
                document.getElementById("classe").value = json[0].classId;    }


        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "json.json", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "ra":12346,
      "name":"Pedro Santos Neves",
      "degreeId":1,
      "classId":1
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "ra":456798,
      "name":"Maria Antônia Silva",
      "degreeId":2,
      "classId":1
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "ra":752156,
      "name":"José Carlos do Prado",
      "degreeId":3,
      "classId":2
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "ra":852348,
      "name":"Aparecido Costa Ribeiro",
      "degreeId":4,
      "classId":2
   },
   {  
      "id":5,
      "ra":454643,
      "name":"Mariana Antunes Aguiar",
      "degreeId":6,
      "classId":2
   }
]
```

Comment: Certo cara só que agora está retornando undefined nos campos.

Comment: @Leandro coloca o Json aqui, undefined é erro de como vc ta puxando a invormação do json.

Comment: Adaptei o script para você ter um exemplo funcionando.

Comment: `[
 {
  "id":1,
  "ra":12346,
  "name":"Pedro Santos Neves",
  "degreeId":1,
  "classId":1
 },
 {
  "id":2,
  "ra":456798,
  "name":"Maria Antônia Silva",
  "degreeId":2,
  "classId":1
 },
 {
  "id":3,
  "ra":752156,
  "name":"José Carlos do Prado",
  "degreeId":3,
  "classId":2
 },
 {
  "id":4,
  "ra":852348,
  "name":"Aparecido Costa Ribeiro",
  "degreeId":4,
     "classId":2
 },
 {
  "id":5,
  "ra":454643,
  "name":"Mariana Antunes Aguiar",
  "degreeId":6,
    "classId":2
 }
]`

Comment: `function loadDoc() {
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var students = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     var degrees = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     var classes = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("aluno").value = students.name;
      document.getElementById("serie").value = degrees.degreeId;
      document.getElementById("classe").value = classes.classId;
    }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("GET", "students.json", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }`

Comment: voce quer que quando clicar em "Carregar" ele carregue qual dos alunos?

Comment: Atualizei o meu post com um exemplo usando o seu json. Repare que `json[0].name` pega o nome do primeiro aluno. Se quiser do segundo será `json[1]` e assim por diante.

Comment: Correto Karl tbm já tinha conseguido aqui. Agora estou com outra dúvida, até fiz outra pergunta aqui no fórum. Como listar todos os alunos, séries(degreeId) e classe(classId) deste arquivo.